# Google Sheets Script Edit Needed - Data Validation

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below script in my google docs. It only updates on cells that I update manually, not on cells that are updated via a formula. How can I edit this?

Thanks,

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Info")

  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell()

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){

    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

    var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1,  datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

    if(makeIndex != 0) {

    var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 4).setDataValidation(validationRule);

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is an intended behavior that `onEdit` triggers only on manual edit.

**But there is a workaround:**

- Create a secondary sheet into which you import the original sheet with [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)
- Replace your `onEdit` trigger by an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onChange` trigger
- `onChange` is able to detect updates of `IMPORTRANGE`

Comment: Thanks, but I need some help with this. The formula isn't working correctly and not updating. I have the google sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1plhDvq9s_1S4trAAXA2hwuEoefLNuW9c_nbYHk_QC5E/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to make Column E be a dynamic dropdown based on column A. It should pull from the Info Tab based on the headings in column A. I followed the instructionst o create an On Change trigger, but can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Did you connect the sheets (Google prompts you to do so when you enter the formula)?  You can e.g. create a new sheet named "Dummy" and introduce in the cell `A1` of this sheet the formula `=IMPORTRANGE("PASTE_HERE_THE_URL_OF_THE_SPREADSHEET", "Info!A1:I5")`.  Also modify `var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell()` to `var activeCell = datass.getActiveCell()` . Then the script will fire correctly `onChange` and will modify your sheet `Info`. However, right now your script is not doing what you described in your comment that you want to do, but this is already another question.